# Can't compile .xslt into java class file

Tags: java, xml, xslt

I have been trying to compile xslt file into java class and keep getting this errors. Not sure what I am doing wrong here:

```
java com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.cmdline.Compile test.xslt

java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.compiler.Parser.parse(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.compiler.XSLTC.compile(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.compiler.XSLTC.compile(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.compiler.XSLTC.compile(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.cmdline.Compile.main(Unknown Source)
Compiler errors:
Could not compile stylesheet
```

my test.xslt file:

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?> 
 <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">  
   <xsl:template match="/hello-world">
     <HTML>
       <HEAD>
         <TITLE></TITLE>
       </HEAD>
       <BODY>
         <H1>
           <xsl:value-of select="greeting"/>
         </H1>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="greeter"/>
       </BODY>
     </HTML>   </xsl:template>   <xsl:template match="greeter">
     <DIV>from <I><xsl:value-of select="."/></I></DIV>   
  </xsl:template> 
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Are the greater than signs (`>`) part of your .xslt file?

Comment: you mean closing tag sign (>)? Yes, it is part of it.

Comment: No initially in the file, every line started with a closing tag sign. Other question: what command did you use to compile the file?

Comment: java com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.cmdline.Compile test.xslt

Comment: am able to compile ...change the test.xslt to test.xsl and try

Comment: what command did you use use Naren? and what version of JDK you have?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the version of Xalan from Apache. It's generally more reliable than the version that ships with the JDK.

Comment: It's not mine... It's one of my competitors! But if the answer works, please accept it. Not that I care about the brownie points (I'm too old for that), but the green tick-mark is helpful to subsequent readers of the thread.